# Why is Artifactory downloading massive amounts from Fastly?

Tags: artifactory, fastly

We have Artifactory deployed locally.  Our network team reports that Artifactory has begun downloading large amounts of data from Fastly, to the extent that it is having a major impact on our network.  They report,

> a ton of data is pulled from 199.232.192.209 - SKYCA-3 and thats
> fastly

It happened yesterday between 3:30 and 9:30, and started again today at 10:00.

Can anyone tell us why Artifactory is doing this, and how can we control or stop it?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a result of a build (or another automated process) which is hitting a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-RemoteRepositories) in Artifactory, requesting artifacts which are not cached and resulting in outgoing requests to the proxied external repository.
It is common for public repositories to use services such as Fastly to serve requests.

The best way to troubleshoot it, would be looking at the Artifactory request [log](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Logging) and see who generated this load of requests and which repository was used.
In addition, the Artifactory log file should contain logging for such outgoing requests, for example:

```
2021-05-20 21:11:45,306 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] [INFO ] (o.a.r.HttpRepo      :443) - jcenter downloading https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/cfg4j/cfg4j/3.3.2/cfg4j-3.3.2.jar 36.17 KB
```